# My HDMI screen won`t display 1920x1080p desktop with Radeon HD 7850 2GB

Tags: graphics-card, resolution, hdmi, amd-radeon, amd-catalyst

Specs relevant:

1. Graphics Card: AMD Sapphire Radeon HD 7850 2GB (should support up to 4096 x 2160)
2. Screen       : BenQ GL2460 (native resolution is 1920 x 1080)
3. Cable        : HDMI cable connected to my graphics card's HDMI slot, and to my screen's HDMI slot.

Well, I know it is unnecessary to point out cable and where it is connected, but now I won't have to answer to that if one would ask me if I did that.

Yesterday I had a TV running with my Radeon HD 7850 2GB on 1360 x 768 @ 60Hz. Today I got my new screen mentioned above, and on catalyst control center (yes, latest version) it says that recommended resolution is 1920 x 1080, so I set it to that. Then my desktop won't use the whole screen. And since my graphics card should be able to support this, I thought it would be something with outdated drivers, so I reinstalled every driver associated with graphics/screen etc.

This did not help. So I found out that the highest possible resolution which uses the whole screen was 1680 x 1050 @ 60Hz which isn't what I paid for.

Since I am not satisfied with working all this summer saving up money for this, I did everything I could do by searching forums and stuff. I saw people having similar problems but nothing which had anything to do with the desktop not filling out the border correctly.

I don't know what else to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check the Overscan function in the CCC software . The ben-Q is a monitor?  so could you connect with the DVI?

Comment: A description of overscan and why it might be necessary: http://www.engadget.com/2010/05/27/hd-101-overscan-and-why-all-tvs-do-it/

Comment: Assuming you are using Windows (you may want to clarify which Os and version you're using) -- Does Windows recognize the BenQ monitor by name?  Have you tried installing [the driver for the Monitor](http://www.benq-eu.com/product/monitor/gl2460/downloads)?

Comment: My Windows 7 Home Premium 65-bit is recognizing my BenQ monitor by name yes. Drivers? I got a CD which contained a user manual and color tests, but no drivers. Right now benq`s website seems to be very slow so I can`t check if there are any drivers there. One thing to mention, CCC wont list 1920 x 1080 in the "basic" tab, I have to go to the HDTV tab to choose 1080p. But in control panel i get 1920 x 1080 as a recommended option. And, I read fast through the link about overscan, but that didnt seem to be just as big borders as i got here, hard to explain how big they are... Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem and finally solved it. It has to do with overscaling, as @ChrisInEdmonton pointed out in the comments. You have to do the following:

- Open the Catalyst Control Center
- Display the `My Digital Flat Panels` menu.
- Click on `Scaling options (Digital Flat Panel)`
- Turn `Scaling` to 0%

This will solve your issue.